# EF Core joining tables

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, entity-framework

I have just started with EF and am stuck with relationships. I have two tables (Point and Prop) and I want to get the result table (Result) joining these tables.

```
class Point {
  public int Id { get; set;}
  public int Type { get; set;}
}

class Prop {
  public int Id { get; set;}
  public int PointId { get; set;}
  public int Foo { get; set;}
  public int Bar { get; set;}
}

class Result {
  public int PointId { get; set;}
  public int PontType { get; set;}
  public int Foo { get; set;}
  public int Bar { get; set;}
}
```

The problem is that there might be zero, one or many Props for each point and I want to have some logic here.

- if there are no Prop with PointId for Point, just skip this Point
- if there is only one Prop for Point, just combine these
- if there are many Props for Point and there is Prop.Foo == Point.Type, take this one otherwise take any pair Prop-Point

So, I understand how to solve this with series queries - select Ponts, select Props, foreach etc.
I'm wondering if it might be done with a single query (I believe yes, but have no idea how). I played with GroupJoin and GroupBy, but it seems that EF core is not good with that. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: `Point`, `Prop`, `Foo` and `Bar`, please consider making the names a little bit more realistic so that we can understand your problem better.

Comment: _"I played with GroupJoin and GroupBy"_ - the point of ORMs is that you don't have to use RDBMS-style syntax in your code.   Just use EF _Navigation Properties_.  `context.Customers.Orders.OrderLine`

Comment: See the [relationships documentation](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration). I.e. let EF do the join, write a 'where' to filter your items, and a 'select' to create the result-objects.